# check if user is on homepage

Tags: grails, gsp

I have a header template where I want to check if a user is on the home page (index.gsp). I tried it with:
    <g:set var="isHome" value="${params.get("controller") == null}" />

But that returns also true for errors where I have no controller. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can always set a flag from the action, bound to index.gsp, in the Model while redirecting to the template to indicate the home page, and use it in template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your header is in a layout, you can use Sitemesh page parameters. Add to your home page:

```
<parameter name="isHome" value="true"/>
```

Then in your layout:

```
<g:set var="isHome" value="${pageProperty(name: 'page.isHome')}"/>
```